# duplicate all products from one store to another store with different stock values

Tags: magento-1.9, products, category-products

I am new in magento I want to duplicate all products and categories from one store to another store e.g

store 1

category 1 
 -> product 1

Store 2

category 1 (duplicate)
 -> product 1 (duplicate)

I have searched alot but did not found any solution kindly help me on this. Plus I found one extension https://amasty.com/duplicate-categories.html It duplicates all categories but not sure duplicate the products or not. May be it just assign one product to multiple categories.
Help much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything that will do this in admin. There is this code to [duplicate products programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43151/programmatically-duplicated-product-not-getting-displayed-in-frontend).

I think your best bet would be to export your products using Magento's standard export functionality, manipulate in something like Open Office (Excel can sometimes cause line-ending issues) so that SKUs are unique and website or store is changed. This can then be reimported. I would suggest trying a small number of rows including a configurable product first!

The neatest option of using the same products with different products you've seemingly realised is not possible, as stock in Magento 1 (and indeed in Magento 2 CE) is global. Although there is some stub code and database columns suggesting otherwise, the ability to maintain stock separately for different websites or stores does not exist.